# Typescript: Generic function for creating a lookup object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I currently have a function to which I can pass an array of objects, where the objects all have the `_id` key. From that object the function creates a lookup object, which has the `_id` fields as keys and the corresponding objects as values.

```
function createLookupById<S extends string, T extends object & { _id: S }>(source: Array<T>) {
    return Object.fromEntries(source.map((el) => [el._id, el]));
}

/*
Example input: [
  { _id: "foo", otherKey: "value" }, { _id: "bar", yetAnotherKey: "abc" }
]

Output: {
  "foo": { _id: "foo", otherKey: "value" },
  "bar": { _id: "bar", yetAnotherKey: "abc" }
}
*/
```

How can I make this function even more generic, so that I can specify the key which it shall use for creating the lookup (currently fixed to `_id`) while still keeping the type checking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a parameter, `keyFn: (v: V) => string` -

```
function createLookup<V>(
  source: Array<V>,
  keyFn: (t: V) => string
): { [k: string]: V; } {
  return Object.fromEntries(source.map((el) => [keyFn(el), el]));
}
```

```js
console.log(createLookup(
  [
    { _id: "foo", otherKey: "value" },
    { _id: "bar", yetAnotherKey: "abc" },
  ],
  el => el._id,
))
```

```js
{
  "foo": {
    "_id": "foo",
    "otherKey": "value"
  },
  "bar": {
    "_id": "bar",
    "yetAnotherKey": "abc"
  }
}
```

View it on [typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQGTnAaxAAcAeANQD4AKAZzhBQjQC5EBBFFDATwsoA0iAmh4AxMG2pQ25AJSIAvJUS0oKGGADmctgG9EAbQJs1G7QF1ZAbkQBfRHoBQiV4nRRGSAPIAjAFZo0AB0wChwALYAomDqMGi0dAxMaMERGMTU1GgANgrKRiLiYNl5QrkWcnLWTnZOThAI9DmpOXBa1KiY2HiEJNQuRoOuBgD6MAAmbABEwPjTQnBQABZoKADSojMAbhg5IGjT9gLDjojjU4jTvhgoC4g8aFDsYEurG1tXGL4QR3YnrgsAMQuSUKlywQuJyqTiAA).

---

One limitation you are experiencing is `Object.fromEntries` will only create an object where the keys can be `string` -

```
interface ObjectConstructor {
    /**
     * Returns an object created by key-value entries for properties and methods
     * @param entries An iterable object that contains key-value entries for properties and methods.
     */
    fromEntries<T = any>(
      entries: Iterable<readonly [PropertyKey, T]>
    ): { [k: string]: T; }; // ⚠️ k: string

    ...
```

I might suggest you use a more suitable lookup type, like [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) -

```
function createLookup<K,V>(source: Array<V>, keyFn: (t: V) => K): Map<K,V> {
  return new Map(source.map((el) => [keyFn(el), el]))
}
```

Now the `_id` could be a `number` or any other type -

```
const data = [
  { _id: 123, otherKey: "value" },
  { _id: 456, yetAnotherKey: "abc" },
]

const numDict = createLookup(
  data,
  el => el._id,
)
```

```js
console.log(numDict)
```

```js
Map (2) {
  123 => {
    "_id": 123,
    "otherKey": "value"
  },
  456 => {
    "_id": 456,
    "yetAnotherKey": "abc"
  }
}
```

```js
console.log(numDict.get(123))
```

```js
{
  "_id": 123,
  "otherKey": "value"
}
```

Comment: `<PK extends PropertyKey>(keyFn: (t: V) => PK): { [P in PK]: V }` should work just fine, right? The unsuitability of map is the fact that it isn't an object with known properties. It's a different data structure which serves different use cases.

Comment: Sure that's fine when your objects can be converted to a `PropertyKey` but that's not always the case. And `source` ids are likely only known at run time, so typescript can't make an object of them at compile time. I understand a Map is different but a lookup table is exactly what they're here for ^_^

Comment: Indeed the only problem with map is the anemic api. But I'm not saying this is a bad answer. I voted for it. However, I would add an overload that captures the extra type info in the original object returning variant.

Answer (score 2):

You could add another generic parameter to specify your lookup key.

```
function createLookupById<
  K extends string,
  S extends string,
  T extends { [Key in K]: S },
>(key: K, source: T[]) {
  return Object.fromEntries(source.map((el) => [el[key], el]));
}

const result1 = createLookupById("_id", [
  { _id: "foo", otherKey: "value" },
  { _id: "bar", yetAnotherKey: "abc" },
]);

const result2 = createLookupById("customId", [
  { customId: "foo", otherKey: "value" },
  { customId: "bar", yetAnotherKey: "abc" },
]);
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABBATgUwIZTQGTnAaxAAcAhATwEkATAHgChFEBpRNAD2zGoGdEeoKGGADmAGkaIAym05pufAUNESmAFVldeiAN6IA2szTlEwlgF0AXNMQBfCQD4AFAWPXmY-nBAoIaa2r65gCUupLoUD5IAPIARgBWaNAAdMAocAC2AKJggjBoPE483r5oyRkYxE5OaAA2oQC8DgZ1+q7k5p51IcEA3PS29PQQCAKI6DwgtVAAjIgNyOhYuPhEZFTUTgBEAPow1Fue+pJ6e9TWW8D4h4hwUAAWaChG5BcAbhi1IGhbdqq6iDOF1iGBQN3IaCgAEEwHdHs83IgthhYhBfvZ6CF+sNRlBxgUplAAEzzRaYbB4QgkCg0bYQEACTI0G7HJh6emMjI0C5XOA3OFPF7vT7fdH-dkMqBM85IkFgzwQ6Gwh6CxHI1FizF9ehAA)

Comment: How could I modify this solution, so that the string "_id" is the default value for the key to map by? I've tried `key: K = "_id"`, but this yields an error (TS2322).

Comment: I actually tried implementing a default parameter in the first place. But you‘ll get problems with the generics and I couldn’t come up with a proper solution that does not require a type assertion. You see `key` cannot be assigned a default of  `“_id“` since `K` could potentially have a completely different type.